# Is there any algorithm to solve multi patterns search in multi text?

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search

So far as I just use wu-manber/aho-corasick algorithms to search patterns in text one by one, a bit courious is there any effective way to solve this problem?

I have hundreds words(patterns) and hundreds articles(text), now wanna find which article include most words, or even sort the articles by it included patterns.

Answer (score 0):

[Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) or [Commentz-Walter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm) will simultaneously match multiple patterns in a text

Comment: thanks, ya I know these two, but seems they are just use for multi patterns search in a text, so I wanna know if there any good algorithms for multi patterns search in multi text.